# What is this output of Sklearn tfidf_vectorizer

Tags: scikit-learn, statistics, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

First, I applied the tfidf_vectorizer onto my training data.

```
X_train_counts = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
```

Then I try to output the tf-idf value of the sentence 'programming'.

```
test = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(['programming']).reshape(1, -1)
print(test)
```

The result is

```
(0, 45295)  1.0
```

What this 1.0 represents? I thought it might be the tf-idf or idf value of the word 'programming' as the tf value in this case is 1.

Then I tried

```
test = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(['programming upgrade']).reshape(1, -1)
print(test)
```

The result is as follows.

```
(0, 60314)  0.7968362696657073
(0, 45295)  0.6041952990095505
```

If 1 is the tf-idf value, then, in this case, it should be 0.5 as the tf value is 1/2, but this is not the case.

So what this number represents? Seems not the tf value, not the idf value, and not the tf-idf value.

Confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that the default setting for the tfidf_vectorizer is the norm "l2" instead of "l1".

The output of the tfidf_vectorizer is the tf-idf matrix and the number is therefore the tf-idf value.

By default, the tfidf_vectorizer utilized the 'l2' norm (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html).

Here is some side by side comparison of the resulting tf-idf values:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

doc1 = ['programming upgrade']

tfidf_l1 = TfidfVectorizer(norm='l1')
tfidf_2 = TfidfVectorizer(norm='l2')

tfidf_l1.fit(docs)
tfidf_2.fit(docs)

print("Output tfidf_transformer with l1 norm:")
test = tfidf_l1.transform(['programming upgrade']).reshape(1, -1)
print(test)

print("Output tfidf_transformer with l2 norm:")
test = tfidf_2.transform(['programming upgrade']).reshape(1, -1)
print(test)
```

And this returns:

```
Output tfidf_transformer with l1 norm:
  (0, 1)    0.5
  (0, 0)    0.5
Output tfidf_transformer with l2 norm:
  (0, 1)    0.7071067811865475
  (0, 0)    0.7071067811865475
```

So just specify your tfidfVectorizer to use the norm "l1".